# What happens when I have two pointers pointing to the same object?

Tags: objective-c

Suppose I'm in viewDidLoad and I point a delegate property to self.
Now both self and that property are pointing to the same object.

Is it ok for there to be multiple pointers to the same object or will this cause problems?
When does the pointer get deallocated?

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        someDelegate.property = self;
    }
```

Comment: If the two pointers are both `strong` (`weak` pointers do not count on the reference count) then the object will be deallocated when the last of the two pointers will change value (become nil or points to another object). The only risk is if you create a cycle. In that case your object won't be deallocated. Read here (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-1000810) for more details. Of course if you are not using ARC you need to correctly send the appropriate `retain` and `release`

Comment: If you are using ARC (Automatic reference counting, which is the default now) then you need to read up on ARC and how it works. If you're using manual reference counting, then you should read up on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very normal to have multiple pointers to the same object.

The *pointer* is deallocated when it goes out of scope. That probably isn't what you're really asking, but it's worth exploring so you understand what `self` really is.

The method `viewDidLoad` is really a function:

```
void viewDidLoad(id self, SEL _cmd)
```

(It's not really called `viewDidLoad` in this form, since that would cause name collisions, but let's pretend it is.)

Your `viewDidLoad` translates roughly into:

```
void viewDidLoad(id self, SEL _cmd)
{
    objc_msgSend(self->someDelegate, "setProperty:", self);
}
```

What's important to understand here is that `self` is a function parameter. It lives on the stack and is destroyed when the function returns and its stack is popped. The `objc_msgSend()` call then pushes another copy of `self` onto the stack as its third parameter. That copy will be destroyed when `objc_msgSend()` returns. These are copies of the *pointer*, not the object they point to.

So there are *many* pointers to this object, all created and destroying in the normal course of function calls.

Now to the question of when does the object pointed to by `self` get deallocated, that's based on reference counting. It is destroyed when the number of strong references to it becomes zero. Typically things called `delegate` only have a weak reference. It is likely that `setProperty:` will create a strong reference. So as long as the `property` points to the object referenced by `self`, that object will stay alive (at a minimum).

Comment: A pointer is just a variable on the stack. I wouldn't say "the pointer is deallocated". Object instances get deallocated, not the pointers to the object instance. The pointers simply affect the reference count.